# Silverlight DataForm within a UserControl

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, toolkit, dataform

I have the toolkist dataform dfAddr inside a usercontrol called ucAddressInformation.  I am placing ucAddressInformation inside another usercontrol called ucParentInformation.Initially when ucParentInformation loads, dfAddr AutoEdit property is false. So  When I am in ucParentInformation and I call the AutoEdit = true to edit for dfAddr, it gives me "element is already the child of another element".  I'm not sure what the setting AutoEdit property does in the guts, does it add the same element again to my parent usercontrol?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an error within your xaml, but without actual code and a better explaination I would say we dont have enough information. Can you post some sample code of your xaml and code behind?

Comment: That's correct, my xaml was incorrect. If you have a dataform, and inside that dataform you have a xaml control like a label that has no binding, it throws up that error. I will post